# CSS image alignment in relation to paragraph

Tags: html, css

So I want to give my users the option of uploading an image and placing it in relation to a paragraph in the text. The options I want to provide are these:

[image: image positions]

So, the way I solved this was by adding a clear element after all images in position 1, 2 and 3 as well as 6, 7 and 8. For reasons regarding editing (users should be able to change the position "live" and see the result directly) I want to remove that clear element completely, yet still have these options. Positions 2, 4, 5 and 7 are no problem, it's the left/right aligned over/under that is causing problems, and I don't know how I could solve this. Any pointers are welcome

```css
.img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.imgpos_1 {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.imgpos_2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.imgpos_3 {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.imgpos_4 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.imgpos_5 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  float: right;
}

.imgpos_6 {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.imgpos_7 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.imgpos_8 {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="img imgpos_1">1: over to the left</div>
<div class="img imgpos_2">2: over, centered</div>
<div class="img imgpos_3">3: over to the right</div>
<div class="img imgpos_4">4: left-aligned in text</div>
<div class="img imgpos_5">5: right-aligned in text</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent molestie, felis id tempus fringilla, mi metus aliquam nunc, tristique elementum sem purus vel libero. Mauris ac rutrum velit. Suspendisse at cursus nibh, et dictum tellus. Mauris venenatis elit eget nulla porta, ultricies ornare sem convallis. Aliquam magna lectus, congue sit amet rhoncus in, efficitur ut metus. In congue eget magna quis aliquet. Nulla ullamcorper rhoncus leo, et tempor nisi pellentesque vel. Integer ornare lacus blandit dolor bibendum feugiat. Integer eu metus et lacus feugiat rutrum at sed justo. Duis vel tellus magna. Suspendisse quam nisi, porta et erat nec, porttitor feugiat nunc. Morbi at tortor vel sem condimentum rhoncus. Nunc bibendum gravida odio, et finibus dui posuere sit amet.
</p>
<div class="img imgpos_6">6: under to the left</div>
<div class="img imgpos_7">7: under, centered</div>
<div class="img imgpos_8">8: under to the right</div>


<div class="img imgpos_1">1: over to the left</div>
<div class="img imgpos_3">3: over to the right</div>
<p>
  Phasellus lacinia, nisl at lobortis sollicitudin, enim ante auctor enim, id sagittis massa diam eu dui. Mauris sed ultrices dolor. Curabitur ut quam vitae ligula congue fringilla. Nullam vitae vestibulum turpis, non posuere est. Vivamus faucibus iaculis bibendum. Pellentesque ut lectus erat. Praesent dictum suscipit metus, eu blandit diam. Ut tempor mattis felis maximus rutrum. Quisque tristique elementum iaculis. Vestibulum lacinia venenatis ligula, laoreet molestie libero semper id.
</p>
```

And here is an image of how I want the end result to look like:

[image: Desired result]

Comment: How do users change the position, decide which one they want?

Comment: why mis-use the float hack for a grid layout? why not simply use css-grid in the first place? Even Flexbox would do the job.

Comment: @battaboombattabaam Using a form or clicking on the image and choosing from the graphics above in a popup. Not sure how the method they use is important though...

Comment: @tacoshy Cool, show me a jsfiddle of the above html using grid/flex to achieve the end result graphics

Comment: just think differently. Think of it as a 3 row layout. the middle row would be the poaragraph where float actually would be ok as it is the intended tool for that case. However the top and bottom row need to be independant from the first row. As such float isnt needed and could purely donw with flexbox

Comment: @tacoshy I know, but that requires that you change the html though

Comment: You don't want to modify the html?

Comment: @battaboombattabaam One reason is that image widths are percentages of their parent width, putting them into flexed divs will make them percentages of that div. so if I have two images, one at position 1 and one at position 3, i.e. top left and top right, I need two divs to put them in, each 50%, making them half their size

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like below:

```css
.img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* added */
body {
 text-align:center;
}
p {
 text-align:left;
}
/**/
.imgpos_1 {
  float: left;
  clear:left; /* added */
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
/* added */
.imgpos_3 + p,
.imgpos_1 + p,
.imgpos_2 + p{
  clear:both;
}
/**/

.imgpos_2 {
  display:inline-block; /* added */
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.imgpos_3 {
  float: right;
  clear:right; /* added */
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.imgpos_4 {
  float: left;
  clear:left; /* added */
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.imgpos_5 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  float: right;
  clear:right; /* added */
}

.imgpos_6 {
  float: left;
  clear:left; /* added */
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.imgpos_7 {
  display:inline-block; /* added */
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.imgpos_8 {
  float: right;
  clear:right; /* added */
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="img imgpos_1">1: over to the left</div>
<div class="img imgpos_2">2: over, centered</div>
<div class="img imgpos_3">3: over to the right</div>
<div class="img imgpos_4">4: left-aligned in text</div>
<div class="img imgpos_5">5: right-aligned in text</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent molestie, felis id tempus fringilla, mi metus aliquam nunc, tristique elementum sem purus vel libero. Mauris ac rutrum velit. Suspendisse at cursus nibh, et dictum tellus. Mauris venenatis elit eget nulla porta, ultricies ornare sem convallis. Aliquam magna lectus, congue sit amet rhoncus in, efficitur ut metus. In congue eget magna quis aliquet. Nulla ullamcorper rhoncus leo, et tempor nisi pellentesque vel. Integer ornare lacus blandit dolor bibendum feugiat. Integer eu metus et lacus feugiat rutrum at sed justo. Duis vel tellus magna. Suspendisse quam nisi, porta et erat nec, porttitor feugiat nunc. Morbi at tortor vel sem condimentum rhoncus. Nunc bibendum gravida odio, et finibus dui posuere sit amet.
</p>
<div class="img imgpos_6">6: under to the left</div>
<div class="img imgpos_7">7: under, centered</div>
<div class="img imgpos_8">8: under to the right</div>


<div class="img imgpos_1">1: over to the left</div>
<div class="img imgpos_3">3: over to the right</div>
<p>
  Phasellus lacinia, nisl at lobortis sollicitudin, enim ante auctor enim, id sagittis massa diam eu dui. Mauris sed ultrices dolor. Curabitur ut quam vitae ligula congue fringilla. Nullam vitae vestibulum turpis, non posuere est. Vivamus faucibus iaculis bibendum. Pellentesque ut lectus erat. Praesent dictum suscipit metus, eu blandit diam. Ut tempor mattis felis maximus rutrum. Quisque tristique elementum iaculis. Vestibulum lacinia venenatis ligula, laoreet molestie libero semper id.
</p>
```